# Строчная и заглавная буквы в названиях станций метро

Tags: орфография

Почему в названиях станций метрополитена "Гостиный Двор", "Старая Деревня", "Охотный Ряд" все слова пишутся с заглавной буквы, а в названиях "Воробьёвы горы", "Сретенский бульвар", "Филёвский парк" — со строчной?

Answer (score 4):

[**Написание названий остановок, станций, аэропортов**](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5a8dacd39e29a2c758a5ce30/napisanie-nazvanii-ostanovok-stancii-aeroportov-5ae35dca5f49678c67a725db)

> В названиях станций метро и остановок наземного транспорта с прописной буквы пишется только первое слово и **все те слова, которые пишутся с прописной буквы в оригинальных названиях**; такие названия заключаются в кавычки: станции «Сокольники», «Ломоносовский проспект», «Красные Ворота», «Проспект Мира»; остановки «Школа», «Детский парк», «Октябрьская площадь», «Парк Культуры». Прописная буква во втором слове в названиях **Красные Ворота** (площадь), **проспект Мира**, **парк Культуры** пишется по правилу написания названий площадей, улиц, парков; **если такие названия становятся названиями станций или остановок, прописная буква сохраняется**.

[**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE)

> В названиях станций метро с большой буквы пишется первое слово названия, а также все слова, которые пишутся с большой буквы в составе соответствующих топонимов. А в составе топонимов *площадь Революции* и *улица Кузнецкий Мост* слова *Революции* и *Мост* пишутся с большой буквы. Ср.: *Ленинский проспект* – и станция метро *«Ленинский проспект»*.
>
> Обратите внимание: в названии станции метро *«Воробьёвы горы»* (до 1999 г. – *«Ленинские горы»*) слово *горы* (как и в самом топониме) пишется строчными.

Comment: Любопытно, что название станции "Гостиный Двор" и в Википедии и на всех схемах, которые я посмотрел в Гугле, написано с ошибкой: ["Гостиный двор"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE)). Похоже, что традиция такого написания сохранилась ещё с советских времён.

Comment: @grizzly  Грамота пишет: _на официальной схеме линий Московского метрополитена, разработанной Студией Артемия Лебедева по заказу Департамента транспорта Москвы, все названия станций написаны правильно (в соответствии с орфографическими нормами)_.  Я посмотрел, вроде всё сходится, только заметил, что _Парк культуры_  - с маленькой.

Comment: Ну мы же не о Москве говорим (или я Вас не понял). Может, в Москве тоже есть станции, в названиях которых изменялось написание прописных / строчных букв в последние десятилетия? Мне просто любопытно, почему питерцы сопротивляются новым правилам написания. В советские времена так назывался универмаг в Ленинграде — "Гостиный двор". Да и сейчас сложно найти печатное издание, в котором это название написано по-другому (попытайтесь сами поискать в гугло-книгах). И это не просто невнимательность — в Википедии, например, раньше было правильно, потом только исправили.

Comment: @grizzly  Да, конечно, Гостиный Двор и Деревня не в Москве. Мой комментарий просто был по горячим следам, да и в вопросе  большинство станций московские.

Comment: Ок. Но всё же давайте и в комментариях будем писать правильно: "Гостиный Двор" :)

Comment: Так я уже не знаю, как правильно :).  Это вопрос не собственно русского языка, а официальной фиксации.

Comment: Правильно как в словарях. Это название есть и в орфографическом словаре и в специальном словаре Лопатина "Как правильно? С большой буквы или с маленькой". Или Вы подумали, что я придираюсь к ответу? Нет, ответ я поддержал, а комментарий оставил, поскольку ошибка очень распространена.

Comment: Нет, всё нормально, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Не все примеры верны ("[Гостиный двор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)" - станция, [Гостиный двор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3)) - универмаг).

*Первая* заглавная буква начинает название самой станции, во *втором* слове названия  первая буква может быть заглавной только при вхождении в него названия **соответствующего городского топонима** (ул. [Охотный Ряд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4)), в котором она присутствует на отдельных основаниях. Например, станция "*Площадь Мужества*" названа по топониму "*площадь Мужества*", где "площадь" - имя нарицательное (аналогично "горы", "бульвар", "парк"); при этом новая заглавная буква появляется в начале названия станции. Для сравнения: название станции "*Сенная площадь*" повторяет название площади (*Сенная площадь*), где слово во второй позиции *не* требует заглавной буквы.
В случае "Старой Деревни" название тоже совпадает с одноименным топонимом, в котором второе слово по историческим причинам утратило нарицательный смысл деревни и формально зафиксировано в написании с заглавной буквы в названии городского квартала. Такое происходит не всегда, например, в названиях петербургских улиц продолжают фигурировать как нарицательные обозначения "[(Шкиперский) проток](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA)", "(18-я) линия" и др.

Comment: По поводу "Гостиного Двора" Вы заблуждаетесь. Уже много лет нужно писать оба слова с прописной буквы, нравится нам это или нет. Всё-таки в этих вопросах Википедия не самый авторитетный источник информации. Даже [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=249690) и то надёжнее.

Comment: "Грамота" напрасно пытается конструировать устоявшиеся названия по своду каких бы то ни было правил: достаточно посмотреть _подряд_ результаты поиска по гугл-книгам (они начинаются с самых современных).

Comment: Да, я смотрел гугло-книги (я писал об этом в комментариях к другому ответу). Но всё равно считаю это недостаточным основанием требовать от автора вопроса присоединиться к бунту против официальных словарей (в особенности на этом ресурсе).

Comment: Как можно видеть в Интернете,  Гостиный Двор/двор пишут как кому нравится, и это вполне объяснимо. Гостиный двор - это исторически нарицательное сочетание, в одном городе могло быть несколько гостиных дворов. Гостиный двор в Москве - это название конкретного гостиного двора на Ильинке, поэтому  с прописной буквы пишется первое слово. Почему прописная буква стала использоваться в слове "Двор"? Это произошло, вероятно, потому, что функции торгового здания расширились, теперь это торгово-выставочный комплекс Гостиный Двор, да еще исторический памятник вдобавок.

Comment: Как расширились, мы видим из рекламы.  «Гостиный Двор – излюбленное и традиционное место проведения таких масштабных и массовых мероприятий как балы, в том числе выпускные и Новогодний бал Мэра Москвы, детские ёлки, выставки, ярмарки, fashion-показы и концерты». Но тем не менее  используются оба варианта названия, даже иногда в одном тексте. Почему? По традиции, а также из-за того, что люди не могут объяснить и выбрать  правильное название и остановиться на нем.  А пока не могут, так и будет продолжаться. https://redkassa.ru/venue/gostiniy_dvor

Comment: В Москве это может иначе писаться - а станция метро там тоже есть такая?

Comment: Вроде бы нет. Ближайшие к Гостиному Двору станции метро — «Площадь революции» и «Китай-город».

Answer (score 3):

***Гостиный Двор, Старая Деревня, Охотный Ряд*** –  в этих названиях второе слово имеет условное значение, так как не соответствует современным реалиям (нет уже ни ряда, ни деревни, ни торгового двора в **обычном** понимании этого слова). Соответственно, второе слово не  является родовым наименованием и входит в состав имени собственного.

***Воробьёвы горы, Сретенский бульвар, Филёвский парк*** – эти имена дублируют географические названия, а в них горы, парк, бульвар – это именно родовые наименования (нарицательные существительные).

Интересная **информация** об изменении в написаниях

В качестве примера можно привести такие названия: ***улица Кузнецкий Мост и площадь Красные Ворота,*** в которых слова ***мост*** и ***ворота*** писались как с прописной, так и со строчной буквы.

Улица Кузнецкий Мост получила свое название по имени моста, перекинутого через речку Неглинку, по которому ежедневно ходили московские кузнецы, служившие на Пушечном дворе. В 1819 году, когда реку заключили в трубу и над нею образовалась современная Неглинная улица, мост был снесен.

Красные ворота были первой триумфальной аркой в России (их построили в честь победы в Северной войне в 1709 году, но затем несколько раз перестраивали). С середины XVIII века арка стала называться Красными воротами – через них проходила дорога на Красное село. В 1927  году ворота  уничтожили как «мешающие проезду городского транспорта».

Слова *мост и ворота* когда-то реально существовали, поэтому они сохраняются в современных названиях. Однако, в любом случае, для названия улицы и площади, они являются не реальными, а условными, поэтому эти слова следует писать с прописной буквы.